# make intellij sometimes stop at underscores and sometimes not

Tags: intellij-idea

sometimes I want to select everything including underscores and sometimes I don't. I want to be able to manipulate that behavior using a hotkey or similar

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207073835-Where-to-set-word-boundaries-for-Ctrl-Arrow

there exists that setting to globally enable it or disable it but that is not what helps me

sometimes I want it to stop on `_` and sometimes I don't.

just an example:
I have this code line:

```
      $this->wp_user->remove_role(MOTR_USER_ROLE_ORGANIZATION_TEMP);
```

and I want to add:

```
      $this->wp_user->add_role(MOTR_USER_ROLE_ORGANIZATION_ACTIVE);
```

now if stop on underscore is enabled I have to click soo many times to get to _TEMP at the end. But if it is disabled I have to click a lot as well to delete `remove_`  from the function call. I want to manipulate that behaviour using a plugin or similar. Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 0):

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/194-toggle-camel-humps seems to work you need to change the binding in the keymap though as default is assigned to ctrl+shift+a which is already in use in my case